# Making Change with least amount of Coins using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, coin-change

Hello i'm having trouble writing this function.

The objective is to write a function that computes the least amount of coins needed to make change. The function has to use recursion and you are not able to use loops of any kind.

The reason why i'm having a lot of trouble with this problem is that the return type is a struct of all of the coins:

```
struct Martian {
int pennies;    //Represent one cent
int nicks;      //Represent five cents
int dodeks;     //Represent twelve cents
};
```

The function looks like this:

```
Martian change(int cents) 
{

}
```

This is a homework question so i'm not asking for an answer, but i'm just having a lot of trouble trying to figure out what the base cases should be for this one. This is what i have so far:

```
Martian cool = {0, 0, 0};

if(cents < 0)
{
    Martian cool = {0,0,0};
    return cool;

} 
else if(cents == 0)
{
    Martian cool = {0, 0, 0};
    cool.pennies = 1;
    return cool;
} 
else if(cents > 12)
{
    cool.dodeks++;
    cents -= 12;

}
else if(cents > 5)
{
    cool.nicks++;
    cents -= 5;
}


    cool.dodeks += change(cents - 12).dodeks;
    cool.nicks += change(cents - 5).nicks;
    cool.pennies += cents;

    return cool;
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question? I don't quite get it. (How to write that thing is clear though.)

Comment: It's never wise to use variable names such as `cool` or function names such as `awesome_solution` when displaying faulty code ;-)

Comment: Sorry I'm just stuck on what the base cases for this recursion is

Answer (score 0):

There are at least these issues.

`Martian` change to  `struct Martian`
when declaration and Usage.

Example of defining a struct:

```
        struct Foo
        {
                    int x;
                    int array[100];
        };
```

Declaration and Usage Example:

```
        struct Foo f;  
        f.x = 54;
        f.array[3]=9;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question. What is the point of structures and recursion when you don't need them, or even loops for that matter?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pennies, dodeks, nicks;
    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &pennies);
    dodeks = pennies / 12;
    pennies -= dodeks * 12;
    nicks = pennies / 5;
    pennies -= nicks * 5;
    printf ("dodeks: %d, nicks: %d, pennies: %d\n", dodeks, nicks, pennies);
    return 0;
}
```

Having established a simple algorithm let's embellish it with recursion to suit your homework. You haven't made it clear whether it's a *requirement* to use a `struct` for the change, so I won't. If it is - there is something left for you to do!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COINS 3

char *coins [COINS] = {"dodeks", "nicks", "pennies" };
int value [COINS] = { 12, 5, 1 };

void change (int money, int coin) {
    int count = money / value [coin];
    money -= count * value [coin];
    printf ("%s: %d, ", coins[coin], count);
    if (++coin < COINS)
        change (money, coin);
    }

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int money;
    if (argc < 2) return 1;
    sscanf (argv[1], "%d", &money);
    change (money, 0);
    printf ("\n");
    return 0;
    }
```